# redux with router keep state when changing url

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, store

I have this issue:

I have a simple routing technique wrapped inside redux, like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </React.Fragment>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
```

And I have a  simple `Link` in my `App component` like this

```
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

when I navigate to `About` by clicking the `Link`, everything is fine and my store is not reset, but here's the question:
Is there any way to keep the state when I enter the URL in address bar manually or by refreshing the page (hitting F5)?

Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Redux store application will loose state as soon as you refresh the page:

If you want to store something which you want even after page refresh use local storage present in all browsers.

There is something called hot reloading in redux which will not loose data post refresh.

But with your current code store will reset, this is expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, honestly I though about local storage but was wondering if miraculously there was another way around!.

Comment: @AmirShahbabaie in `localStorage ` data will persist even after you close the tab , but in `sessionStorage` data will loose after closing of tab i.e. closing of session. . so according what you need you can choose among `redux` , `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`

Comment: What about using Redux Persist?

Comment: You can use redux persist. The only issue I see with redux persist is maintaining multiple tabs cache.

Answer (score 1):

Although, local storage seems to be the solution, but if there is something you want on all the pages, you should dispatch action to get data in the `App` component in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

`App`, being the most parent component, will set data into the redux store every time the page is loaded, and further routing will obviously not lead to loss of your data from redux.

This is a great solution for cases where you need to store information like 'profile info', that can be accessed on every page anytime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you talk about two different use-cases: navigating to another page (or going back in browser history stack) without loosing the current Redux state, and persisting state on refresh or between site visits. The second one is already covered by the previous answers, but the first one could be achieved with `useHistory` hook from React Router. Here's an example from the official documentation:

```
// https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

The button from the example could be replaced with any HTML element, including `<a>`, also using this hook allows you to run additional checks or business logic in your `handleClick` function, like for example resetting some "current" pieces of Redux state, saving something entered on a page to the state/local storage before going, etc.