# Persisting data without redux-persist or localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, once again, I've been facing this issue of persisting the state tree. In login, for the user to persist, I dispatched an action from my main App.js and got the current logged in user like this:

**App.js**

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")

    if (authToken) {
        this.props.dispatch({ type: "TOKEN_VERIFICATION_STARTS" })
        this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
    }
}
```

Now, I have a form and when it is submitted I'm redirecting the user to the feed where I will show the post title, description in a card form. But as usual, the postData is disappearing after refresh.

It means do I have to make another route, similar to the /me route that I made for getting the current logged in user? And dispatch an action again from the componentDidMount() in App.js?

**NewPostForm.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { addpost } from "../actions/userActions"

class NewpostForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            postTitle: "",
            postDescription: "",
            maxLength: 140
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        const postData = this.state
        this.props.dispatch(addpost(postData, () => {
            this.props.history.push("/feed")
        })
      )
    }

    render() {
        const charactersRemaining = (this.state.maxLength - this.state.postDescription.length)
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="postTitle"
                    value={this.state.postTitle}
                    className="input"
                    placeholder="Title"
                    maxLength="100"
                />

                <textarea
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="postDescription"
                    value={this.state.postDescription}
                    className="textarea"
                    maxLength="140">
                </textarea>
                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>

                <div>
                    Characters remaining: {charactersRemaining}
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
    return store
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewpostForm)
```

**addPost action**

```js
export const addpost = (postData, redirect) => {
    console.log("inside addpost action")
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: "ADD_post_STARTS"
        })
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/new", postData, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": `${localStorage.authToken}`
                }
            })
            dispatch({
                type: "ADD_post_SUCCESS",
                data: { post: res.data.post },
            })
            redirect()
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: "ADD_post_ERROR",
                data: { error: "Something went wrong" }
            })
        }

    }
}
```

**Feed.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Feed = (props) => {
  // const postTitle = (props.post && props.post.post.post.postTitle)
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <header className="card-header">
        <p className="card-header-title">
          {/* {postTitle} */}
        </p>
      </header>
      <div className="card-content">
        <div className="content">
          The text of the post written by the user.
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer className="card-footer">
        <a href="#" className="card-footer-item">
          Edit
        </a>
        <a href="#" className="card-footer-item">
          Delete
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Feed);
```

Comment: @FMCorz as far as I know localStorage.getItem is a synchronous function

Comment: My question here is how to persist the post data on refresh, like when I'm redirecting the user to the feed, for the first time, everything shows up- the post title, description, etc, but on refresh, it does not.

Comment: @DanielB. You're right! I removed my comment.

Comment: Can you please add your "/feed" component code?

Comment: Added Feed Component. @Niraj

Comment: Just for the test: If you are not redirecting and simply add link or button after adding post to redirect there because I think there is some race behavior between update state and redirect

Comment: I didn't get your point @Niraj.

Comment: When you dispatch an action, is it adding into the store?

Comment: Yes, it is. However, on refresh, it's breaking.

Comment: @Niraj I'm talking about this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719203/11873593

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it looks like you are using response of `/api/v1/posts/new` in your feed page however trying to access local state of **NewPostForm.js**

```
this.state = {
   postTitle: "",
   postDescription: "",
   maxLength: 140
}
```

Instead of using local state to save form data which cannot be shared to another component(unless passed as props which is not the case here) you may need to save data to redux store so that it can be shared across different route

```
 handleChange = (event) => {
   const { dispatch } = this.props;
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   dispatch(setPostData(name, value));
 }
```

You action may look like:-

```
export const setPostData = (name, value) => ({
     type: "SET_POST_DATA",
     name,
     value,
});
```

After that you can use **this.props.postTitle** on feed page

Edit: in order to keep state between page reload (full browser reload), you may need to either fetch all data on mount(higher order components are helpful) or use local storage.

Comment: @metalHeadDev Just saw your comment on question by refresh do you mean full browser refresh(webpage reload).

Comment: Do you mean the other question I asked?

Comment: Wouldn't that vanish too from the redux store? How are we dispatching an action on handleChange?

Comment: Yes, it will vanish, in short you can solve it either by calling each endpoint on every reload or by storing data in local storage and after that initialize store using local storage on reload. Storing data to local storage is seems to be less costly as there will be no latency of fetch.

Comment: You may need above change while using local storage so that all data required for feed page have enough data to load. Additionally I would recommend to save current route information. its better to use https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router instead of react-router-redux as this package is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I know you want without redux-persist but the redux normal behavior force to initialize store again from scratch. If you want to persist your state even refresh your page, I would recommend the following package:

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

If you are losing your state on a page redirect or traveling to a different route using react-router you will want to use:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux